# Как указать различные расширения к одному файлу image?

Tags: javascript, изображения

Как указать путь к файлу в js, если не известно каким будет в итоге расширение картинки(jpg или png)
То есть файл с названием img1 может иметь расширение либо jpg либо png, можно ли как-то указать их одновременно, если одного не существует, значит берется другое.

const img1 = new Image(40, 40);
img1.src = "img1.png" //or "img1.jpg"

Comment: а от чего зависит расширение? в какой момент оно будет приходить?

Comment: Изображения лежат уже в папке учебного проекта, но не знаю точно каким будет финальное расширение картинки, чтобы в коде прописать к нему верный путь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот как вариант. Здесь `img1.onerror = function(){/* код */}` срабатывает как раз тогда, если картинка не была найдена, в таком случае выполнится код внутри этой функции. В данном примере он не нашел файл img1.png и пошел дальше искать файл img1.jpg, а не найдя и его пошел выполнять код дальше и нашел img1.gif. Важный момент: не забудь оставить в конце пустую функцию `img1.onerror = function(){}`, как у меня в примере.

```js
var img1 = document.createElement("img");
img1.setAttribute('height', '40px');
img1.setAttribute('width', '40px');
img1.setAttribute('src', 'img1.png');
img1.onerror = function(){
  img1.setAttribute('src', 'img1.jpg');
  img1.onerror = function(){
    img1.setAttribute('src', 'https://i.postimg.cc/BvGSjV02/img1.gif');
    img1.onerror = function(){};
  }
};
document.body.appendChild(img1);
```

Comment: Спасибо, да получилось!!! Изучаю сейчас js и доп  вопрос финальное img1.onerror = function(){};  - это для отлова ошибки, если ни один из путей изображения не будет найден? и еще консоль браузера все равно пишет, что была ошибка, при этом код работает как надо, можно ли как-то это исправить?

Comment: Финальный `img1.onerror = function(){};` нужен для того, чтобы в случае, если ни один файл не будет найден, то браузер бы не зацикливался на попытке прогрузить картинку, которой нет. Можешь убрать эту строчку и увидишь что имеется в виду. По поводу ошибок в консоли, то они собственно и появляются для того, чтобы сообщить, что искомый файл не найден. Если не нравятся ошибки, то можешь попробовать переопределить стандартную реализацию console.error или использовать `console.clear()`, но это уже отдельная тема, лично я не пробовал таким заниматься.

Comment: Понял! спасибо за уточнение!)